Unable to sync the project in Lady Bug Android studio when create the new Project
I am facing an issue in Android Studio (version: Ladybug) while syncing my project. The problem occurs when I either create a new project or add a new library to the build.gradle file. The sync fails with the following error:
Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\Anees Ahmed\.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\ba81abf71439bd977876206c4c50399c-e1222552-f433-4c8c-8db4-e8f03878e1e0) to immutable location
I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:
Invalidate Caches & Restart - Did not resolve the issue.
Cleared the .gradle folder - The problem persists.
Reinstalled Android Studio - Still facing the same error.
Environment Details:
OS: [Your OS, e.g., Windows 11, 64-bit]
Android Studio Version: Ladybug
Gradle Version: [Your Gradle version, e.g., 8.1]
Questions:
What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?
Are there specific configurations or permissions I need to check for the .gradle directory?
Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Try upgrading gradle to the latest stable version of 8.11.1 as there are a number of Bugs in Gradle around this, some of which should be fixed in the latest version.
Or downgrade grade to 8.7 which seems better.
You can do this by editing the gradle-wraper.properties file line
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.11.1-bin.zip
to edit the version number.
Gradle Releases listed at https://gradle.org/releases/
and now 8.12 is available
